# Viewing website on mobile browsers - zooming Issue

Tags: iphone, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, zooming, parallax

I've developed a website based on bootstrap responsive (built on wordpress, with parallax fx) but I wasn't eager to design a specific iphone layout (no budget) so I've set the viewport meta tag to scale down the content when on iphone:

and that worked great for displaying on iphone: you see the full layout as on desktop.

The problem is the lack of pinch-zoom capabilities: you can see the full layout but you can not zoom in.

I've tried almost all the possible combination of viewport tag, eg:

But nothing seems to work :(

Could the problem being the use of 100% width on background?

Website is http://dev.website.com/wp

Thank you

ps: this is my first question, so be kind :)

-m.

Comment: So to get this right... you want it to be zoomed all the way out but have the ability to zoom in?

Comment: correct, I want it to display at 0.25 but user should be able to zoom in

Comment: have you tried omitting the viewport tag altogether?

Comment: yes, I've tried even with no viewport-tag at all, it's a little bit bigger (with some little problem on the parallaxed img) but anyhow no zoom

Comment: actually, at earlier stage, it didn't even scroll, but it was a known issue due to the skrollr framework, solved by wrapping all the to-be-scrolled content in a <div id="skrollr-body"> (with z-index: 1;). Don't know if the zooming issue could be related, but it seems no other skrollr user face that problem.

Comment: mh seems the problem is with the scroll/animate framework not supporting zooming https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/206